# how to send and receive Json?

Tags: asp.net, json, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a client (on xamarin.android) and there is a server (asp.net web forms). I want to pass a json POST request from the client to the server, to process the data in the database. I'm kind of like sending a json (although not sure), but I do not know how to accept it. Here is my send code:

```
    var user = new UserJson
    { 
Name = "Vladimir", 
Age = 21 
}; 
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user); 

JsonWiew.Text = jsonData; 

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("my web server (here the home page address)"); 
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonData); 

request.Method = "POST"; 
request.ContentType = "application/json"; 
request.ContentLength = data.Length; 

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) 
{ 
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
} 

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

To send data, you can use httpclient class and send a post/get request to your web service.

To take data, use httpclient class and request data from your web service and ensure that your web service is sending data in json format.

So let you store the result of your web service response in a string s.

Include newtonsoft.json.linq package in your project to work with json.
Then create object of JObject class and parse your response.

```
Using newtonsoft.json.linq;
String s= //your response from web service in json format//
 JObject obj = JObject.Parse(s);
 var value= obj["key"].ToString();
```

Hope this help.